# Rails Undefined Method when Trying to Divide

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have what should be a simple operation where I want to calculate the percentage completion of something in Rails 3.

In my Object model, I have the following function:

```
def balance
  (self.amount_remaining / self.amount) * 100
end
```

Then, in my Object view, I have the following:

```
<%= Object.balance %>
```

However, I get the following error:

> undefined method `/' for nil:NilClass

Does anyone know what may be causing this error? Should I be making this calculate elsewhere?

Comment: After spending a long time on this today, I answered it for myself just after I posted the question here. My method that was making sure the amount_remaining wasn't nil was malfunctioning. As a result, the variable was nil and created the error. By setting it to 0 instead of nil, it all works fine. I don't see how to create an answer for my own question now, so I'll accept anyone that does then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

```
(self.amount_remaining / self.amount) * 100 rescue 0
```